# can i create 3d delaunay on file series in paraview?

Tags: python, paraview

I have comma separated value file series, meaning it a time series files. Can I create 3d Delaunay triangulation" for all data in the series in a single step?
The file contains minimum 50000 points in 3d space. And I have similar files of 400 nos.

By single step, I mean as the pipeline is created on the file series, does single operation of applying 3d Delaunay triangulation, is carried out on each individual files in the series so as to create a animation.

Comment: "Maybe".  There's a lot of information missing from this question, notably how large the file is, and what you mean by a "single step".

Comment: @Makoto see my edits and help me out.

Comment: are you able to perform the triangulation on a single file? if so, with the same pipeline, load the timeseries and running the animation should give you the result you expect (you can also try to save the triangulation with the option "all time steps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @lib says I found that the pipeline files are animated without any problem. But, take a lot of time.